# C# finding managed thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm using the `System.Threading.Thread` object to create a background-working method. The method loads data which can also be used by the user in the current time (must be read from the same source). That's why I'd like to find the created `Thread` and pause it for the time of current data-loading.

Here comes the problem... How to find the `Thread`?

I've already read about `System.Diagnostics.Process` attempt, but it contains data only about the OS-Threads.
Also I need to say that the method starting the `Thread` is `static` and it's possible but really unwanted to create an object to track the thread. I'm just creating new object and starting it...

`(new Thread(new ThreadStart(...))).Start();`

I've looked through many topic but I found no following question:

*IF IT'S IMPOSSIBLE, THAN FROM WHERE THE **VISUAL STUDIO -> THREAD WINDOW** TAKES INFORMATION!?*

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Why don't you store the thread object into a variable and keep access to it that way?

Comment: _"it's possible but really unwanted to create an object to track the thread"_ Can you explain why it's unwanted, given this would be the usual solution?

Comment: @JamesThorpe : as mantioned it's a `static` method called by `Form` object, to track the thread I'd have to add a member to the caller class but than I'd need to 'send' this `Thread` object to almost every method, because the `Form` doesn't work with the data (only shows it), there is a `static` class to do that. I've also got an idea of creating `Thread` or even `List<Thread>` in the `Program` class, but I think it would be better to leave it as clean as possible. And there's last point: it would be best to know how to find threads for next (maybe more difficult) projects.

Comment: Just don't lose the reference created by `new Thread(...)`.  Store it in a variable so you can find it back later.  Beware that "pausing" is a pretty bad idea, strongly favor keeping threads short and snappy.

Answer (score 1):

If pausing the "reading" thread is truly required, you can have it wait for a signal using the [EventWaitHandle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle) class, set as Manual or Automatic reset depending on your use case, starting unset. The background thread, when it has finished writing to whatever the shared variable location is, can set the signal on the wait handle to release the "reading" thread that was stuck waiting.

If your "reading" thread only needs to pause sometimes, you can use the same wait handle approach, except have it start as "set" in Manual Reset mode while your "reading" thread checks it whenever appropriate. The "reading" thread will skip over waiting for the signal (because it's already set)!

Once your "writing" thread needs to make a change, it would reset the wait handle, causing your "reading" thread to pause when it checks for the signal, update the data, then "set" the signal again to release the paused "reading" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Task` for background work and you can utilize `Continue` method to process the data on completion of task.

```
var task = Task.Run(() => "Test");
task.ContinueWith((str) => "Process data");
```

Or utilize `Name` property of `Thread` class to assign the name.